# How to pass upload data for IformFile in angular8

Tags: angular, iformfile

i am uploading a file and sending data to API hit, when i run this from my application the file details are going as null, but when i run through the postman it works and file gets saved in the API created folder. I am not getting where i am going wrong, tried with all methods i can do.

HTML:

```
 <div class="custom-file" (click)="fileInput.click()" appDragDrop (onFileDropped)="uploadFile($event.target.files)">
                <input hidden type="file" #fileInput (change)="uploadFile($event.target.files)" class="custom-file-input" id="uploadFile" formControlName="uploadFile">
              </div>
```

Ts:

```
uploadFile (files: FileList) {
    this.files = files.item(0);
    this.agentViewDetailsService.uploadFile(this.files).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data,"upload")
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

Service:

```
 uploadFile(file) {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('fileName',  file.name);
    formData.append('file', file);
    formData.append('status', '1')
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().append('Content-Disposition', 'mulipart/form-data');
  console.log(formData)
    return this.http.post(`${user.w9FileUpload}`, formData,{headers: headers})
  }
```

Please help, i am fully stuck here, not getting where i am going wrong

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drag-and-drop-upload-hrsxtg?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

[image]

Comment: Can you show your postman request

Comment: yes i will share image

Comment: Headers part as well

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
uploadFileService(file) {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append("fileName", file.name);
    formData.append("file", file);
    formData.append("status", "1");
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Disposition', 'mulipart/form-data');
    console.log(Array.from(formData));
    this.http.post(`${user.w9FileUpload}`, formData,{headers: headers}).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res)
    })
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drag-and-drop-upload-slme2r?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for response, it is subsrobe or subscribe?

Comment: subscribe. Was a typo

Comment: Hi in my component file i am getting this error, but not sure why,Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.

Comment: if i use your above code, it throws error because here also subscribe i am using and in componet file also subscribe is used

Comment: could you please help me out with other changes

Comment: Check the demo I added

Comment: sorry, actually that uPloadService comes in service file, in my question posted i have uploadFile(files), in that subscribe error is coming

Comment: sorry because i have added one service file, so it is not taking that i guess, but code part what i have pasted there is same i am using in my application

Comment: I can't help without being able to debug

Comment: sorry it is throwing error, i am not able to fix that, actually i have created a service file, so upLoadServiceFile will be in the service file and to call tat service file i have used one more file in ts, thats all